# How do I get Notification of App Insights Application Log Errors?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

We have some Azure web sites/APIs and web jobs that are using the log4net App Insights appender to push our log4net diagnostic logs into to Azure app insights. We want to be notified when errors occur so we don't have to go looking for errors or wait for user error reports. Is there built in functionality in App Insights to be notified? Or should we build a web job to poll somehow and send us alerts?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you want is probably alerting based on an analytics query:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/14428134-add-alerts-based-on-results-of-analytics-queries

which is in preview form and being worked on.  there's no current way to alert on anything but web tests and metric values.

Answer (score 0):

azure portal > *your Application Insight* > Alerts > Add Alert > Choose your Metric.

Comment: this only works with metrics though, so instead of just logging errors, you'd also have to log some kind of metric as well.  and alerts only occur on state changes for metrics, so there's some trickery there.